# How to create :play document/material?

Tags: neo4j

In the default Neo4j installation, there is a sample movie graph database, e.g. by executing the command ":play movie-graph". How can I create such step-by-step guide/training material/slides/mini-deck?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check out the developer documentation on how to create your custom Browser Guide :

https://neo4j.com/developer/guide-create-neo4j-browser-guide/